# Why will this not output the diceroll2 function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a turn-based dice game for my Computer Science GCSEs and cannot understand why a certain part of my program will not run, or at least output.

```
class player1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rolls = 5
class player2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rolls = 5


def dicerollp1():
    print("foo")

def dicerollp2():
    print("2foo")

while player1.rolls > 0 and player2.rolls > 0:
    dicerollp1()
    player1.rolls += -1
if player1.rolls > player2.rolls:
    dicerollp2()
    player2.rolls += -1
```

Shouldn't 2foo be outputted instead of nothing?

Comment: You appear to be trying to use your classes as instances. If you instantiate your classes, the instances you create will have the `rolls` attribute. The classes themselves do not have such an attribute.

Comment: NB: you do not need two identical classes. You need one class with two instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are trying to use the class name to call a class instance method `player1.rolls()` , instead of that, what you should be doing is to use an object of the class to do that.

```
p1 = player1()
p1.rolls()
```

- One class `player` is enough for your code, you don't need two identical classes, and call two instances on it (Thanks @khelwood)
- `dicerollp1` and `dicerollp2` can be moved inside the class, perhaps by adding an additional attribute `player_number`
- You can perhaps change `player1.rolls += -1` to `player1.rolls -= 1`
  So the refactored code will look like

```
#One player class
class player:
    #Player number as attribute to diceroll
    def __init__(self, player_number):
        self.rolls = 5
        self.player_number = player_number

    #One diceroll function
    def diceroll(self):
        print("foo{}".format(self.player_number))

#Instantiate object of class player
p1 = player(1)
p2 = player(2)

#Use them in the logic
while p1.rolls > 0 and p2.rolls > 0:
    #Refer to p1's diceroll
    p1.diceroll()
    p1.rolls += -1
if p1.rolls > p2.rolls:
    # Refer to p2's diceroll
    p2.diceroll()
    p2.rolls += -1
```

Also after your while loop, `p1.rolls=0` and `p2.rolls=5`, and hence `p1.rolls > p2.rolls` will be false and the if will not be executed, hence the output will be

```
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
foo1
```

Comment: If I set the condition to be while p2.rolls >0, how can p2.rolls = -5?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say p2.rolls =5 I have updated that in my answer please take a look @Jonathan